# finally argument showing undefined after react-native upgrade

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise

Recently I upgraded my react-native version from 0.59 to 0.62 and I found out that my .finally functionality broke.

Actually I am returning the value based on finally argument whether it's success or catch, but suddenly after upgrading, the finally argument started returning undefined and the code started breaking, I am not sure how to fix it.

Code:

```
return getParsedError().finally((conData?: any) => { // conData is undefined now, earlier it was an object that I am returning from resolve
  return Promise.reject(conData || error)
}
```

Comment: perhaps your actual code does *something wrong™*

Comment: have you tried a more recent version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately after much of googling, I found out that the finally is behaving differently in latest react-native versions, as the argument is now undefined, so I added some extra conditions to make my code work.

Answer (score 1):

We just used async (try catch finally). Alternatively you can replace the finally with a .then and return something from the .catch which will cause the .then to execute.